# Text editing by user not possible in BrowserComponent (Codename One simulator)

Tags: java, html, webview, codenameone, contenteditable

I am using Codename One to port my Android app to iOS.

My app is not so simple. It has EditText with ImageSpans inside that are not found in Codename One.

So I am opting to using a BrowserComponent and let text be edited inside it.

I am using the simulator, with a simple test app.

It is enough to have something like this:

```
browserComponent.setPage("<HTML><BODY>"
                            + "<div id=\"editText\" style=\"font-size:40px;\" contenteditable=\"true\">This text can be edited by the user."
+ </div></BODY></HTML>","");
```

but what I get is that:

-clicking inside the browserComponent the cursor is not visible

-words are selected instead

-writing or deleting text is not possible at all.

This is the same even if I use a ready-made text editor HTML page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

The editor appears but the same mentioned things happen inside it.

I do not know if it depends on the simulator or Codename One itself, I did not try with other Java environments.

How to have the text editing feature in Codename One BrowserComponent?

Comment: The `BrowserComponent` included in the simulator has many limitations due to JavaFX, as mentioned here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-away-from-fx.html I suggest you to try your code on a real Android device and a real iOS device to evaluate the actual behavior of the `BrowserComponent`.

Comment: @Francesco Galgani Do I have to use their service to test on Android? How to do it? I plan to do that in the future not now.

Comment: You can generate the Android apk using Codename One and then install it on your device or devices using the Codename One build app

Comment: @Francesco Galgani It seems that online builds are available also for the free account to get the apk. But I think that I can develop this particular feature on AndroidStudio and when it is ready I copy&paste in the Codename One project, as native WebView on iOS certainly works. So online builds are not wasted.

Comment: Try to check "Scrollable" in the simulator to disable the scaling. It's possible that this is just JavaFX sucking as @FrancescoGalgani mentioned

Comment: @Shai Almog No, It was not the scaling

Comment: We hope to roll out JCEF support in the next couple of weeks. This will make debugging these sort of things MUCH easier as it would just use Chrome

Comment: I've discussed this with Steve and he says he experienced a similar problem then switched JVMs to solve it. He didn't recall if switching to ZuluFX 8 or to ZuluFX 11 solved it. Regardless once JCEF is out this will be resolved.